# How to store protocol / specification structures

Tags: c#, .net

Implementing an ISO Creator ( as an intellectual exercise mostly ) I need to store cd data structure values.

For example, from page 47 of  the specification https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~varun/cs315p/iso9660.pdf  , in order to store a directory in ISO9660 format I need to store information about various byte fields

[image]

There are other tables, such as Path Tables that store fields and the total number of fields would be in hundreds.

So I could either

1 - Store these in .cs files , 'hard coding' essentially

```
public byte length=1;
public byte ExtendedAttributeLength = 0;
//and so on
```

2- I could store these as Constants in .cs files

3 -I could store these in XML files

4- I could even store these in a database table

Considering that it is unlikely for these values to change, but not impossible, I'm not sure which way i should store the values.

Thank you

Comment: What do you intend to do with it? It is impossible to give a conclusive answer without knowing how you are going to use it.

Comment: I intend to use it to create an ISO from a CD

Comment: So how do yo intend to use the variables? Any code related to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can define all those specs as structs with explicit layout. This way you can specify the offset for each field:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=16, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DirectoryRecord
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   byte RecordLength;

   [FieldOffset(1)]
   byte ExtendedAttrRecordLength;

   ...
}
```

You can then serialize these to byte arrays and presumably save them as parts of the ISO image header or whatever their place is in there.

---

However, if you look at one of the existing C# ISO9660 implementations such as [.NET DiscUtils on CodePlex](https://discutils.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Iso9660/DirectoryRecord.cs) you will see that they do things a bit differently.

For `DirectoryRecord` they have defined a class with `ReadFrom` and `WriteTo` methods and it takes care of reading from appropriate offsets in an input stream. This is one option. On top of that they have some other component that reads the file and delegates reading to sub-components such as this one.

So, you could do it like them. Or you could do it with structs as I mentioned before and have them behave like POCOs only, not extra reading and writing logic. You'll have to do that somewhere else.

Comment: +1 this is a very interesting way of doing this, and I appreciate that you even looked it up. I was looking at iSOcreater, written in c# and it does it by storing all of this as plain bytes.

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it: Regardless of whether the spec will change or not, you need a way that's easy to read and maintain. Unstructured data (plain bytes, as you put it) is not one of them.